# Strip tags, but keep the first one

Tags: php, html, string, strip-tags

How can I keep for example the first `img` tag but strip all the others?

(from a HTML string)

example:

```
<p>
 some text 
 <img src="aimage.jpg" alt="desc" width="320" height="200" /> 
 <img src="aimagethatneedstoberemoved.jpg" ... />
</p>
```

so it should be just:

```
<p>
 some text 
 <img src="aimage.jpg" alt="desc" width="320" height="200" /> 
</p>
```

Comment: Example string, please, and your attempt.

Comment: Also, parsing HTML with PHP is not a very good idea (although we 've all done this at some point I guess). If you can redefine the problem to avoid this, do so.

Comment: but I need to do it with PHP somehow

Comment: There's only one `img` tag in there. I assume further `img` tags may appear at any point?

Comment: Strip all the other IMG tags or all the other tags?

Comment: @Anda: Why's that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Use an HTML parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php

Answer (score 0):

The function from this example can be used to keep the first N IMG tags, and removes all the other `<img>`s.

```
// Function to keep first $nrimg IMG tags in $str, and strip all the other <img>s
// From: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/
function keepNrImgs($nrimg, $str) {
  // gets an array with al <img> tags from $str
  if(preg_match_all('/(\<img[^\>]+\>)/i', $str, $mt)) {
    // gets array with the <img>s that must be stripped ($nrimg+), and removes them
    $remove_img = array_slice($mt[1], $nrimg);
    $str = str_ireplace($remove_img, '', $str);
  }
  return $str;
}

// Test, keeps the first two IMG tags in $str
$str = 'First img: <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img 1" width="30" />, second image: <img src="img_2.jpg" alt="img 2" width="30">, another Img tag <img src="img3.jpg" alt="img 3" width="30" />, etc.';
$str = keepNrImgs(2, $str);
echo $str;
/* Output:
 First img: <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img 1" width="30" />, second image: <img src="img_2.jpg" alt="img 2" width="30">, another Img tag , ... etc.
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to accomplish this with a complex regex string, however my suggestion would be to use preg_replace_callback, particularly if you are on php 5.3+ and here's why. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
$tagTracking = array();
preg_replace_callback('/<[^<]+?(>|/>)/', function($match) use($tagTracking) {
    // your code to track tags here, and apply as you desire.
});
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer and points the OP in the wrong direction. PHP has native HTML DOM parsing functionality, plus third party tools which make that easier to use, and DOM manipulation is a far more suitable method for this.

Comment: I respect your opinion. And while PHP does have DOM parsing functionality, which you also didn't provide for him, here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php - this is a simple solution in terms of simplicity. As for not providing complete code, I didn't see it necessary to do all of the code, but provide the framework so that he can figure out for himself how he wants to use it.

Comment: I didn't provide the links because they've already been provided, both as a comment on the question, and as an answer to a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457833/how-to-use-php-dom-document).

Comment: Providing a framework is fine in general, but you've not really explained it nor pointed out that it should be used with care, and it _is_ such a simple solution that you might have well just added the logic to say "if first image, return matched text, else return empty string", because that's basically all that's missing (well, and the regex updated to only cater for img tags) - that's why I'm saying it's incomplete.

Comment: (p.s. hope this isn't coming across as whingy/whatever - my intent is to be constructive)