# How to use php DOM document?

Tags: php, html, string, dom

Can anyone post a example where you parse a string variable with html in it with this DOM document class?

I need to remove certain tags from this variable..

There are no examples on how to use it on the PHP website

Comment: But there are examples on StackOverflow. Please search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+php and try to figure it out yourself. DOM is easy to use. Only ask a question when you hit a roadblock. Dont ask people to write tutorials for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$document = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document->loadHTML($source);

$rootElement = $document->documentElement;

$unwantedTags = $rootElement->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($unwantedTags as $tag)
{
  $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}
```

Comment: but how do I save it back to $source?

Comment: @Anda: `$source = $document->saveHTML();`