# How to ignore first match in this regex

Tags: php, regex, string

```
$tag = 'img';
$text = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $text);
```

how can I make preg_replace ignore the first match ("img"), and do the replacing just on the others?

Comment: This is the kind of situation where using a real HTML parser would be highly appropriate...

Comment: Don't use regex for this, use the PHP DOM stuff.

Comment: Related to questions: "[Strip tags, but keep the first one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457650/strip-tags-but-keep-the-first-one)" and "[How to use php DOM document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457833/how-to-use-php-dom-document)"

Comment: but the dom thing doesn't work x(

Comment: Then why on earth did you mark [PatrikAkerstrand's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457833/how-to-use-php-dom-document/7457884#7457884) as the solution?! I'm pretty sure it *will* do what you want, you just haven't got it to do so yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for() loop and set $i as 1 to avoid the first value in the array, so something like :

```
 for($i = 1; $tags < count($tags) ; $i++){
 $text = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $text[$i]);
 }
```

but this loop will replace `$text` value everytime its executed, if you want to save it as a string replace the `=` sign with `.=`  or if you want to make an array replace `$text` with `$text[$i--]`

note that this code is not tested!