# XML escaping special character

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, escaping, cdata

How can I escape special characters in a XML file using PHP. I am trying to read the XML file and then escape the special characters if exits. I am trying to make the xml file in CDATA format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to in PHP. Just take an XML Parser which allows you to do CDATA creation (in PHP that one is called DOMDocument) and replace the whole text-nodes with a CDATA of their strings that contain those "special" characters.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you have any example?

Comment: That would be a duplicate question: [How to use php DOM document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457833/how-to-use-php-dom-document)

Answer (score 0):

I feel htmlspecialchars() function can help you to escaping special characters.

If special character are other language i.e. its not belong to utf-8 encoding than this can work

```
utf8_str = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", my_str);
```