# PHP: Remove all <img> tag except for first one

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I have this code that strips all HTML tags except for `<img>` and `<p>`:

```
<?php
        $item->core_body =strip_tags( $item->core_body, '<img><p>');
?>
```

Because my `$item->core_body` contains several `<img>` tags, I want to add another condition: I only want to keep the first `<img>` tag and strip out all the following ones.

Based on the answer:

```
<?php
                    $item->core_body =str_replace('<img','<***',$item->core_body,1);
                    $item->core_body =strip_tags( $item->core_body, '<img><p>');
                    $item->core_body =str_replace('<***','<img',$item->core_body,1);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457650/strip-tags-but-keep-the-first-one?rq=1

Comment: @PRP: [right back at ya](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1230836). Suggested answers all use regex. Not ideal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way: replace the first img-tag with something else, remove the rest of the image tags, replace the first tag with 'img'.

Something like

```
$item= preg_replace('/\<img/','****',$item,1);
$item= strip_tags( $item, '<p>');
$item= str_replace('****','<img',$item);
```

Comment: I have tried it but it's giving me a blank page. Any idea why? (I am editing a component on a joomla website)

Comment: Dit you alter the variables? I did skip the `->core_body` part

Comment: Yes, i did. Sorry I didn't mention it. Please have a look at the code in my edited question.

Comment: My bad, was an answer in a hurry. I've tested the updated answer and now it works. My error: the fourth param of `str_replace` returns the number of replacements, with `preg_replace` the fourth parameter limits the number of replacements. Furthermore, in your line `strip_tags( $item->core_body, '<img><p>');` the second parameter are 'allowable tags' so it would not have removed any of the `<img` tags.